# how do I add a new content-type in soap ui

Tags: rest, soap, soapui, content-type

I need to add an additional content-type to the drop down in the REST Request editor.  How can I do this?  Is there a configuration file that I can modify or something I can modify add a new content type.

Additional Information
I was attempting to set a Header value in the SOAP UI Rest Editor.  I added the Content-Type as a header parameter but it would always take the value in the dropdown section at the bottom of the Rest Editor.

I am asking this quesiton here instead of the SOAP UI because a question like mine was already asked it went unanswered.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried adding it by typing even though it is not in the dropdown?

Comment: Yes.  But it seems that no matter what I do it will only take values in the dropdown.  I checked the filesystem for a configuration to add a new value  but no joy.  I ended using fiddler to get through my current situation but I would like to be able to use the additional features of SOAP UI.

Comment: Usually all the types are available in the drop down. You could not find the format that you looking for?

Comment: You can simply type new content type in the drop down

Comment: I was mistaken I was able to add it via dropdown by typing it in.  I made a mistake when trying it the other night.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a custom header with content type , you can use this or a variation of this

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap;
getAllHttpSteps=testRunner.testCase.getTestStepsOfType(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep)
for (step in getAllHttpSteps){
    def headers = new StringToStringMap() //Use StringToStringMap Object to store headers key/value.
     headers.put("header field","header value")
    //add more header fields if require
     step.testRequest.setRequestHeaders(headers) //setting header in request
}
```